# Codeigniter Update Options not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to update my codeigniter row options but it's not working. This is my code.

```
$result = $this->cart->update(array(
    'rowid' => $rowid,
    'qty' => $quantity,
    'options' => array('Size'=>$comments)
));

var_dump($result);
```

In `$comments`, I have the actual data that I want but for some reason, `options` is not there when I `pre` the contents of cart. Any idea what I may have done wrong?

Comment: The code you are showing appears to be correct according to the current CodeIgniter user guide. Since $result is supposed to be a boolean value, if it is TRUE, then I don't know what to tell you. If it is FALSE, then perhaps you have the wrong rowid ??

Comment: Hi, are you using some popular library for that; or did u create your own?

Comment: I am using codeigniter's default cart. And var_dump is returning me true but I don't see options in my cart :(

Comment: What is the exact value of `$comments`?

Comment: The exact value of `$comments` is "Test"